# list of string to list of colorlover

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, pca

I have a list of 100 strings and I would like to convert them to a list of colorlover colors to be able to use them in plot.py. I have tried multiple options but it always gives me a different color for the same string. The function should work like:

```
hash(string) - > colorlover
```

Any ideas. ?

Here the list of Strings:

```
XIC-FWHM-Q1
XIC-FWHM-Q2 
XIC-FWHM-Q3 
XIC-Height-Q2   
XIC-Height-Q3   
RT-Duration 
RT-TIC-Q1 

...
```

colorlover scale [RdYlBu] would be good.

```
ryb = cl.scales['3']['div']['RdYlBu']; ryb
['rgb(252,141,89)', 'rgb(255,255,191)', 'rgb(145,191,219)']
```

I want to implement a PCA analysis like this https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/principal-component-analysis/ But I have 100's of columns with classes category (Strings) that I need to associate with colors. Then I can't add the colors manually like in the example.

Comment: You need to include an example of the string so we can help you...see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have added some examples of String.

Comment: Please also include examples of what a colorlover colour looks like ( result of your hash function)

Comment: I have added a couple of example of the color code. The main problem is not the colors code is the logic to convert String into color RGB for the `colorlover` scales. Especially if we always want for the same string, the same color.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `colorlover` is actually a python library. It does the string conversion and you don't need to create separate logic for that.

Here is a link to the [documentation](https://github.com/jackparmer/colorlover) and here is a link showing examples of the [strings](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/color-scales/) used for generating colour scales.

**UPDATE**

If you want to define your own colours, [this](https://python-colourlovers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#colour) may be a good starting point. Others may have more experience in this.

**UPDATE 2**

If you need to generate many colours, check [link](https://plot.ly/python/colorscales/) which walks you through  setting colorscales for your variables in Python and Plotly. The *colorscale for Scatter Plots* section may be a good starting point.

I managed to generate a large list of rgb values using the following code:

```
import colorlover as cl
import pprint

pprint.pprint(cl.scales["3"])
```

This produced the following list, from which you can select the rgb values you wish to use:

```
{'div': {'BrBG': ['rgb(216,179,101)', 'rgb(245,245,245)', 'rgb(90,180,172)'],
         'PRGn': ['rgb(175,141,195)', 'rgb(247,247,247)', 'rgb(127,191,123)'],
         'PiYG': ['rgb(233,163,201)', 'rgb(247,247,247)', 'rgb(161,215,106)'],
         'PuOr': ['rgb(241,163,64)', 'rgb(247,247,247)', 'rgb(153,142,195)'],
         'RdBu': ['rgb(239,138,98)', 'rgb(247,247,247)', 'rgb(103,169,207)'],
         'RdGy': ['rgb(239,138,98)', 'rgb(255,255,255)', 'rgb(153,153,153)'],
         'RdYlBu': ['rgb(252,141,89)', 'rgb(255,255,191)', 'rgb(145,191,219)'],
         'RdYlGn': ['rgb(252,141,89)', 'rgb(255,255,191)', 'rgb(145,207,96)'],
         'Spectral': ['rgb(252,141,89)',
                      'rgb(255,255,191)',
                      'rgb(153,213,148)']},
 'qual': {'Accent': ['rgb(127,201,127)',
                     'rgb(190,174,212)',
                     'rgb(253,192,134)'],
          'Dark2': ['rgb(27,158,119)', 'rgb(217,95,2)', 'rgb(117,112,179)'],
          'Paired': ['rgb(166,206,227)', 'rgb(31,120,180)', 'rgb(178,223,138)'],
          'Pastel1': ['rgb(251,180,174)',
                      'rgb(179,205,227)',
                      'rgb(204,235,197)'],
          'Pastel2': ['rgb(179,226,205)',
                      'rgb(253,205,172)',
                      'rgb(203,213,232)'],
          'Set1': ['rgb(228,26,28)', 'rgb(55,126,184)', 'rgb(77,175,74)'],
          'Set2': ['rgb(102,194,165)', 'rgb(252,141,98)', 'rgb(141,160,203)'],
          'Set3': ['rgb(141,211,199)', 'rgb(255,255,179)', 'rgb(190,186,218)']},
 'seq': {'Blues': ['rgb(222,235,247)', 'rgb(158,202,225)', 'rgb(49,130,189)'],
         'BuGn': ['rgb(229,245,249)', 'rgb(153,216,201)', 'rgb(44,162,95)'],
         'BuPu': ['rgb(224,236,244)', 'rgb(158,188,218)', 'rgb(136,86,167)'],
         'GnBu': ['rgb(224,243,219)', 'rgb(168,221,181)', 'rgb(67,162,202)'],
         'Greens': ['rgb(229,245,224)', 'rgb(161,217,155)', 'rgb(49,163,84)'],
         'Greys': ['rgb(240,240,240)', 'rgb(189,189,189)', 'rgb(99,99,99)'],
         'OrRd': ['rgb(254,232,200)', 'rgb(253,187,132)', 'rgb(227,74,51)'],
         'Oranges': ['rgb(254,230,206)', 'rgb(253,174,107)', 'rgb(230,85,13)'],
         'PuBu': ['rgb(236,231,242)', 'rgb(166,189,219)', 'rgb(43,140,190)'],
         'PuBuGn': ['rgb(236,226,240)', 'rgb(166,189,219)', 'rgb(28,144,153)'],
         'PuRd': ['rgb(231,225,239)', 'rgb(201,148,199)', 'rgb(221,28,119)'],
         'Purples': ['rgb(239,237,245)',
                     'rgb(188,189,220)',
                     'rgb(117,107,177)'],
         'RdPu': ['rgb(253,224,221)', 'rgb(250,159,181)', 'rgb(197,27,138)'],
         'Reds': ['rgb(254,224,210)', 'rgb(252,146,114)', 'rgb(222,45,38)'],
         'YlGn': ['rgb(247,252,185)', 'rgb(173,221,142)', 'rgb(49,163,84)'],
         'YlGnBu': ['rgb(237,248,177)', 'rgb(127,205,187)', 'rgb(44,127,184)'],
         'YlOrBr': ['rgb(255,247,188)', 'rgb(254,196,79)', 'rgb(217,95,14)'],
         'YlOrRd': ['rgb(255,237,160)', 'rgb(254,178,76)', 'rgb(240,59,32)']}}
```

If you just wanted to generate colours in the `RdYlBu` spectrum, use the following code:

```
print(cl.scales["11"]["div"]["RdYlBu"])
```

this gives:

```
    ['rgb(165,0,38)',
 'rgb(215,48,39)',
 'rgb(244,109,67)',
 'rgb(253,174,97)',
 'rgb(254,224,144)',
 'rgb(255,255,191)',
 'rgb(224,243,248)',
 'rgb(171,217,233)',
 'rgb(116,173,209)',
 'rgb(69,117,180)',
 'rgb(49,54,149)']
```

The only problem i found was that the highest number i could use was 11, and got an error message for any value above that.I'm guessing that is the entire colour spectrum for `RdYlBu`.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: This strings that they define are fixed color scales .. My string is not those as I mentioned in the example. colorlover defines palettes of colors like `RdYlBu` in these are the examples they are mentioning. My problem is how to conver my String into a valid color in `colorlover`

Comment: You want to define and use your own strings to generate colours?

Comment: probably I didn't make clear my question. I have a list of strings (in my case categorical variables) and I want to generate a color for each of them.

Comment: ok so if i understand correctly, :) - you have 100 variables which happen to be strings, and you want to generate a different colour for each?

Comment: Yes, sorry to take some much time to explain the problem.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Hopefully that will guide you to the solution. cheers